# KbdLayerDescriptor returns NULL at 64bit architecture

Tags: winapi, keyboard

im writing a complex program that analyses users writing, and i have problem when running this application on 64bit OS.
Here is the code you can run to re-interprate the problem.
http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/keylogger-visual-c/
but of course, you need to have 64bit OS, since the program runs correctly on 32bit OS.

after this call

```
pKbd = pKbdLayerDescriptor();
```

this pointer equals NULL

```
pKbd->pVkToWcharTable
```

I have tried to google the solution first, and i found this
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/211107/RegQueryValueEx-programcrash-on-64-Bit
its the exact same problem as i have, but there seem not to be a solution.
So do you have any ideas what can be wrong ?

There is this piece of code in the program and it seems that it takes care of the size differences between pointers on 32 and 64bit architecture

```
#if defined(BUILD_WOW6432)
#define KBD_LONG_POINTER __ptr64
#else
#define KBD_LONG_POINTER
#endif
```

But clearly, its not helping.

Comment: Are you actually using KBD_LONG_POINTER in the VK_TO_WCHAR_TABLE declaration?  Required.

Comment: i used the declarations that are used in the first link i posted - kbdext.h

Comment: The point is that you change the type of the pVkToWchars member to the 64-bit pointer.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understad how this should help me :(

Answer (score 1):

I've just had exactly the same issue with that piece of code.

I'll assume you're compiling to 32-bit but running on 64-bit as I am. If so, then first you need to define `BUILD_WOW6432` before including `kbd.h` (or `kbdext.h` if you're using it).  Secondly, use

```
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_SYSTEMX86, NULL, 0, systemDirectory)
```

instead of `GetSystemDirectory(systemDirectory, MAX_PATH)`.  This means that you always use the 32-bit code, even on 64-bit machines.

This solved the problem for me, hope it helps you :)